# Can a L293D H-bridge be used for this application?

Tags: microcontroller, h-bridge, l293d

I'm building a circuit that is needed for a logging device we have. With some of our sensors the current is going in one direction and with others the other way around. That means that we have a polarity mistake (minus sign) on some of out sensors when we log. We log the voltage drop over a resistor when the current passes through it.

I tried to solve this using a L293D H-bridge (http://www.ti.com/product/L293D/support). I could then change the polarity of the meassured voltage drop over the resistor by enabling 1A and 2A respectively. This worked in principle. However, because of the internal voltage drop the L293D introduced a error in the measurements we could not live with. Are there other H-bridges that introduces almost no voltage drop I could use, or maybe a completely different component?

As you probably can see I'm no electronics expert.

Comment: How and where are you measuring the voltage drop? Why not measure it across 1Y and 2Y?

Comment: The obvious question is, why can't you swap the connections on the sensors that are wired backwards? But if you can't for some reason, you need a [precision rectifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_rectifier), not an H-bridge driver chip.

Comment: How are you measuring voltage (across the resistor)? A single-ended voltmeter might measure voltage *with respect to ground*. Since the L293D switch doesn't pull one of the sensor lines to ground, you get a significant voltage error. A differential voltmeter, or a **differential amplifier** might be a solution. MOSfet H-bridges likely have less voltage drop than L293.

Comment: Hello

Thanks. Think a rectifier is what i need. Actually looking at the circuits, I found that using a configuration with the four diodes like this https://circuitglobe.com/full-wave-bridge-rectifier.html, with my resistor placed like the drawing, probably will work, if I use low leak current diodes.

Answer (score 0):

> We log the voltage drop over a resistor when the current passes through it.

The L293D is a transistor H-bridge. Using this to switch the current direction is not the right way. There are much smaller and better FET based integrated H-bridges available to do such polarity reversal.

However, the above method is a solution to a problem you do not need to solve. If your measurement supports both current directions, the problem is also resolved. You can use a shunt amplifier, such as INA199, to measure bidirectional shunt current.

Comment: Thanks, the INA199 sounds like something that would work great. However, the gain of 50 raises some concerns. We probably need a shunt resistor of 250 Ohm, and currents through from 4 mA to 20 mA, given a voltage of 5 V, and with the gain of 50, we get 250 V on the measurement side. I think that is to high. Also we suspect that such an amplifier could increase uncertainties on the measurements to much.

However, it is perfect that one can measure the voltage independent of the direction. Are there any components with no gain that can do the same, or at least a very low gain?

Comment: @AndersNørløvBerthelsen You can probably find an amplifier suitable, perhaps INA188, or design your own cirucit. Or just a 249 Ohm resistor in series with a 1 Ohm sense resistor. All of those options will be better than passing a sense signal trough a motor driver.

Comment: The INA188 looks promising uncertainty and gain wise, however, I can't see that it is bi-directional, do you know if it is?

Comment: @AndersNørløvBerthelsen INA188 isn't specifically an shunt amplifier. See chapter 8.2 in the [document](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/sbos632/sbos632.pdf).

Comment: Oh I see. I think I have misunderstood how it works. I have a resistor with a 0 to 20 mA current through it. This current can be in both direction depending on which sensor we put in our system. The resistor is 500 ohm so the signal is converted to 0 to 10 V when we measure the drop over the resistor. Our problem is that we measure 0 to 10 V when it is in the one direction, and 0 to - 10 V when it is the other direction, we need 0 to 10 V in both cases. I guess ina188 can't do that.

Comment: @AndersNørløvBerthelsen Measure 0-20V, with 10V as reference level. It's basically what those amplifiers do.

Answer (score 0):

Feels like an odd approach to change polarity.  H-bridges are usually used to change the direction of fairly large currents in actuators, not to change the polarity of a sensor, where you'd really care about voltage drops.  You can probably make it work, I just don't understand why you would want to.

My first option would be software, in the collection system.  If this wasn't an option, I'd consider some sort of low resistance digital switch if were my design, like this SPDT -- https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NLAS4684-D.PDF.  The technology would be very similar, just optimized for a different purpose.

If you need a DPDT, I'll leave it to you to find one.

If you can't deal with a half ohm, you'll never be able to deal with an H-bridge.

Comment: Thanks. No need for h bridge. I just don't know which device to use, and this was the first device I found. It is not an option to do it in the software. So take a look at your suggestion for an alternative component tomorrow